# why Django showing object has no attribute?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hope you are doing well, i am beginner to the django and python, encountered the error while practicing which is on REST API FRAMEWORK of DictField . i took an example on DictField. I have posted a code below please have a look. feel free to ask if you have any questions. please solve the issue. Thanks a lot for your help.

## app1/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class Geeks(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.dict = dictionary


class GeeksSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    dictionary = serializers.DictField()
    child = serializers.CharField()
```

## python manage.py shell

```
>>> demo = {}
>>> demo['name'] = "Naveen"
>>> demo['age'] = 21
>>> obj = Geeks(demo)
>>> serializer = GeeksSerializer(obj)
>>> serializer.data
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "rest_framework\fields.py", line 457, in get_attribute
  return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
 File "rest_framework\fields.py", line 97, in get_attribute
  instance = getattr(instance, attr)
AttributeError: 'Geeks' object has no attribute 'dictionary'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
 File "rest_framework\serializers.py", line 555, in data
   ret = super().data
 File "rest_framework\serializers.py", line 253, in data
   self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
 File "rest_framework\serializers.py", line 509, in to_representation
   attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
 File "rest_framework\fields.py", line 490, in get_attribute
raise type(exc)(msg)

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `dictionary` on serializer `GeeksSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Geeks` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Geeks' object has no attribute 'dictionary'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Geeks` object has a `dict` attribute, not a `dictionary` attribute, so

> 'Geeks' object has no attribute 'dictionary'.

makes total sense.

If you want the `dictionary` serializer field to read from `dict`, set the `source` attribute on the field.

```
dictionary = serializers.DictField(source="dict")
```

Answer (score 0):

The serializer is not fit for the data shape, you can fix it like this

```
class Geeks(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.dictionary = dictionary

class GeeksSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    dictionary = serializers.DictField()
    child = serializers.CharField(required=False)
```